# If JavaScript has first-class functions, why doesn’t calling this function in a variable work?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript is purported to have first-class functions, so this seems like the following ought to work:

```
var f = document.getElementById;
var x = f('x');
```

But it fails on all browsers, with a different cryptic error message on each one.  Safari says “Type error”.  Chrome says “Illegal invocation”.  Firefox says “Could not convert JavaScript argument”.

Why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because in JavaScript functions arent *bound* to context (`this`). You may use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var f = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Comment: To clarify this answer, `this` in `document.getElementById()` is `document`, while `this` where you're executing your scope is the global scope, aka `this` is the `window` object.

Answer (score 38):

When you call `obj.method()` in Javascript the method is passed `obj` as `this`.  Calling `document.getElementById('x')` with therefore set `this` to `document`.

However if you just write `f = document.getElementById` you now have a new *reference* to the function, but that reference is no longer "bound" to `document`.

So your code doesn't work because when you call `f` as a bare function name it ends up bound to the global object (`window`).  As soon as the innards of the function try to use `this` it finds that it now has a `window` instead of a `document` and unsurprisingly it doesn't like it.

You *can* make `f` work if you call it so:

```
var x = f.call(document, 'x');
```

which calls `f` but explicitly sets the context to `document`.

The others way to fix this is to use `Function.bind()` which is available in ES5 and above:

```
var f = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

and is really just a generalised short cut for creating your own wrapper that correctly sets the context:

```
function f(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using ES6's spread operator, you could also try:

```
function f(){
    return document.getElementById(...arguments);
};
```

Babel gives this:

```
function f() {
    var _document;
    return (_document = document).getElementById.apply(_document, arguments);
};
```