# javascript objects, callback and this keyword

Tags: javascript, this, jquery-callback

I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly reference the 'right' 'this' in a jquery ajax callback.

I have a javascript class where I define the callback:

```
Foo.prototype.onCallback = function(response) {
  // 'this' should refer to an instance of foo in both the following cases
  this.bar(...)    
  this.hello(...)
}
```

outside of the class I have:

```
foo1 = new Foo()
myCallback = foo1.onCallback;

$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(response) {myCallback(response); ... }
});
```

Right now I believe 'this' within foo1.onCallback is referring to the html element the ajax call is attached to. How do I ensure that 'this' refers to foo1? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following idiom:

```
myCallback = foo1.onCallback.bind(foo1);
```

In fact you should take advantage of first-class function support in JavaScript even further:

```
foo1 = new Foo()

$.ajax({
  ...
  success: foo1.myCallback.bind(foo1)
});
```

#### See also:

- [If Javascript has first-class functions, why doesn't this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773579)

Comment: the OP indicated that there were other things to be done after the initial callback was called, so you can't just pass it as the `success:` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `context` property of [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
var foo1 = new Foo();

$.ajax({
  context: foo1,
  success: function(response) { this.onCallback(response); }
});
```

...which causes `this` in the callback to reference your `Foo` object.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Rocket. I totally missed that I grabbed the wrong identifier. :)

Comment: No prob, figured it was just a typo, so I fixed it for ya :-P

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

You must either write:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(response) { foo1.onCallback(response); ... }
});
```

or this:

```
myCallback = foo1.onCallback.bind(foo1);
```

Note that `Function.bind()` requires ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply add the statement `alert(this);` to see the if it is foo1.

Comment: Your alert would output [object Object]