# Alias function in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If Javascript has first-class functions, why doesn’t this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773579/if-javascript-has-first-class-functions-why-doesnt-this-work)

When I try to make an alias function for `document.getElementById` as below:

```
f = document.getElementById;
```

But, when I try to call:

```
var e_fullname = f(“fullname”);
```

It was rised an error:  `Could not convert JavaScript argument`

And below is OK:

```
var e_fullname = f.call(document, “funname”);
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: You have some unusual quotes. What editor are you using?

Comment: I don't think this issue because an editor. I just to understand how Javascript work?

Comment: @vietean: You should definitely read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: This issue is not because of the editor, but issues could be caused by one: `var str = “Hello, world!”;` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are four ways of calling a function:

1. Function invocation: `f(p1, p2)`
2. Method invocation: `obj.f(p1, p2)`
3. Apply or Call invocation: `f.apply(obj, [p1, p2])`, `f.call(obj, p1, p2)`
4. Constructor invocation: `new f(p1, p2)`

In all these cases, `f` is just a reference (pointer) to a function object (an object with a `[[Call]]` internal property). What makes it behave different in all these cases is the way the function is called, and that matters a lot.

So, `f` is just a reference to the `getElementById` object, there's no difference between `document.getElementById` and `someOtherHTMLElement.getElementById`; the function doesn't hold back a reference to the object that references it.

If you want to bind a certain *"owner"* object, use the `bind` method:

```
var f = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Answer (score 7):

`getElementById` is a method on document.  To call it, the interpreter needs to have the function body itself, the object to call it on (document in your case), and the arguments.

When you do `f = document.getElementById`, you're copying the function body, but not the object to call it on.

When you do this:

```
f.call(document, “funname”);
```

You're providing both the object to call it on, and the arguments.

If you want to be able to call f directly, you need to get the "document" object stored in there somehow.  Easiest is:

```
var f = function(name){return document.getElementById(name)}
```

This creates a closure which holds on the the value of document for you.

You can also use bind() to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> Creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to
>   the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any
>   provided when the new function was called.

```
var f = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

It was introduced in ES5, so be aware of browsers not yet supporting this version of ECMAScript!

As an alternative you could use the [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method of jQuery, added in version `1.4`

```
var f = ​$.proxy(document.getElementById, document);
```

Or you could delcare `f` as an function of its own (this is a more verbose solution).

```
var f = function() { return document.getElementById(arguments); }
```

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the JavaScript version you are referring to is specific to Mozilla. If you are considering other browsers, it is more helpful to refer to the ECMAScript version. `.bind` was introduced in ES5.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling I changed it in the text.

Comment: The last one doesn't work, arguments cannot be re-transmitted directly like that. You need to do something like `document.getElementById.apply(document, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );`

Comment: Why the `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`? Can't you just use `document.getElementById.apply(document, (arguments);`

Comment: Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) changes the arguments array-like object to a proper array.

Nowadays you should also be able to use Array.from(arguments)  to get the same effect.

Here is an article from hacksparrow discussing it in more detail:
https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript/array-like-objects.html