# JavaScript - Assigning namespaces to local variables for use in constructors, not sure what is happening?

Tags: javascript

Is something like this valid?

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var Smtg = window.some.namespace.Something,
        Els = window.another.namespace.Else;

    var smtg = null,
        els = null;

    smtg = new Smtg();
    els = new Els();

    smtg.doSomething(els);
}());
```

Namely the use of renaming the constructor to a shorter local variable and then instantiating from this shorter local variable?

Only I get strange errors like `TypeError: Smtg is not a constructor`. When window.some.namespace.Something is;

```
window.some = {};
window.some.namespace = {};
window.some.namespace.Something = (function () {
    "use strict";

    this.doSomething = function (els) {
        els.blah();
    }

});
```

(imagine window.another.namespace.Else is similar to the above)

I had assumed this would all be ok, no?

If it is ok what will the likely cause be of the error? I can't find what might be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alias function in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000020/alias-function-in-javascript)

Comment: `some` and `some.namespace` both have to be a object before you can assign a value to `some.namespace.Something`

Comment: The above is psuedo code taken from a much larger piece of code, all relevant namespaces exist in the original, I'll edit the question to avoid this confusion.

Comment: You don't really have `this.doSomething(else)`, right? Because that would be a syntax error (`else` is reserved, and you're missing the `function` keyword).

Comment: yes correct I wrote this into stack overflow, I do not use else in my real code, I'll edit that one out too, *facepalm lol

Comment: eeek I'm a java programmer lol, old habits ^^

Comment: You should always [lint](http://www.jslint.com/) your code ;)

Comment: JSHint is showing no errors, I of course do always check here first, the above is psuedo code, I should have checked that a bit before posting sry

Comment: If you remove all syntax errors and broken references (like `window.another.namespace.Else`), it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrncG/

Comment: What does `console.log(full.path.to.your.constructor)` gives you? Is suspect it wont be a `function`.

Comment: Yes already tried that and it was indeed a function(), clicking in firebug took me to the correct .js file and I could see everything fine. Interesting point too is that if I concattenate all my files into one then the error goes away?!?!

Comment: @bfavaretto I appreciate that th psuedo code may well work but my real code is much larger and I'm reluctant to post the whole thing :( I imagine that the error is coming from somewhere else in my code but I have no idea which bit to post (If I knew that... lol). I don't know what I've done that would generate that error so I don't really know what to look for but I'll hunt it down and post up what my problem is if I find it.

Comment: Check what `Smtg` *is*. Your error says it's not a constructor, hence not a function. So, what is it?

Comment: try creating a new object in the console `new window.some.namespace.Something`

Comment: Ok - Thanks all for your suggestions, I have found the bug. It was in my html of all places! (not the JavaScript, which is why I have been going round in circles) I'll write an answer to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the browser will throw the error `TypeError: Smtg is not a constructor` if and only if `Smtg` is indeed not a constructor.

if Smtg is a function in the console then you are probably trying to create a new instance before declaring it. or its being overwritten for the scope that you are trying to use it in

Example - this will throw a error

```
window.name = {}
window.name.space = {}
window.name.space.something = (function(){});

function test(){
   var scopeOverwriter = function(){
       this.name = "not a obejct anymore";
       this.getNewSomething();
   }

   scopeOverwriter.prototype = {
       getNewSomething = function(){
           return new name.space.something();//name is a string here
       }
   }
   return new scopeOverwriter();
}

test();
```

Comment: I was **trying to create a new instance before declaring it** even though I didn't mean to! see my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely valid, so long as `window.some.namespace.Something` is an object (i.e. not a literal).

This is because objects in JavaScript are like pointers in C (i.e. they "point" to some place in memory). Assigning `Smtg` to `window.some.namespace.Something` simply means they both point at the same place in memory.

For example, you can say:

```
var body = document.body;
alert(body.innerHTML); // same as alert(document.body.innerHTML);
```

The problem is in your code. Here's a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/yRuvf/

Comment: This is the answer to the question in the title but not the answer to my problem therefore I accepted Josh's answer, if I could accept this too I would :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have a concatenator that itterattes through all the files in my project and concattenates and minifies the files and creates a dev html with all the scripts individually. Recently I changed the name of my application's entry point, in the concattenator (which I wrote quickly) I had reference to the file by just writing the string everywhere instead of havin it in one static variable (I know...) I changed it to the new one and updated it to use a static variable and forgot to update one of the references.

The application removed the entry point from its list and added it to the end.

However because I forgot to update one of the references the file was added twice, once in the list where it was found and once at the end. So when the first file was included (in my dev html which lists all the scripts individually) it had references to 'undefined' instead of the functions, in the latter of the scripts all was ok so my application would run even with the error that was displaying so I was thoroughly confused.

This is why the concatenated file worked with no errors cos it did not rely on the same references. eeesh! What a polava.

Therefore when I began thinking, I must have a systematic error with renaming the namespaces, which made me look in completely the wrong location.

So... when the error was generated it was indeed not a constructor, as it was not defined at that time. But later it was defined... and the code would run.

Everyone who answered helped me find this bug, I was able to find it once I knew that the javascript was valid as I knew I should be looking in another location for the bug.

I wish I could accept more than one answer! Alas I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something like that:

```
var Obj = {};
```

then this is not object with constructor that you can use with new:

```
var o = new Obj();
```

constructors in javascript is basically a function so you can do something like this:

```
var Obj = function(){};

var d = new Obj();
```

Comment: So how can we tell what is the error if we don't know what you are doing ?

Comment: However what you have written is perfectly true. 

But I was creating objects and then adding a function to the object which was instantiated using `new`. My JavaScript was, it turns out, perfectly valid. The problem was elsewhere. Thank you for your contribution though ;)