# Is console.log a regular object?

Tags: javascript, console.log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If Javascript has first-class functions, why doesn’t this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773579/if-javascript-has-first-class-functions-why-doesnt-this-work)

In Chrome, the following produces *Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation*:

```
g = console.log;
g(1);
```

Why does this happen, and why can't I treat `console.log` like a regular object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because you've lost the reference to `console`. You're just calling `log` directly, with no context. You can call the function in the context of `console` to make it work:

```
g.call(console, 1);
```

Or, to save you from doing that every time, you can bind the function back to the `console` object:

```
var g = console.log.bind(console);
```

**References**:

- [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (not used here, but still of interest)
- [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)