# Shortening the name of a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on an SE userscript that I've written in Vanilla JS. It works mostly through DOM manipulation, so I frequently use `document.getElementById` and `document.querySelector` and other similar functions. These functions work well, but they are long and, even though I have tab completion, I want to shorten the time it takes to write these out. I have thought of using another function with a shorter name to replace these longer functions. To replace `document.getElementById`, I would have a function name `byId` that would take in an Id string, `id`, as a parameter, then return the value of calling `document.getElementById` on `id`. The function would look like

```
function byId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

which could then be called simply by writing

```
byId('id-name');
```

I have seen [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8773579) about debugging someone's attempt to do this, but my attempt works. I am just wondering about how this practice is looked upon.

So, should this practice be used? Could this worsen performance or even break the functionality of a program? Is there anything that could be *helpful* about it (besides shortening the function name)?

Comment: why not just use `var byId = document.getElementById.bind(this)` as the linked question suggests?

Comment: @Jamiec I actually didn't see that question until after I had written most of the question, so I just decided to keep what I originally had.

Comment: If to care about others reading your code, I wouldn't do that. You say you have tab completion, so whats the problem then?

Comment: @kitty My text editor isn't really the best at tab completion. It gets confused a lot.

Comment: @michaelpri I would try tweaking your editor or switch to another one, there are plenty of them with sane completion!

Comment: @kitty I probably will soon, I don't think I'm gonna use this though, but I'm gonna wait a little before I fully decide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly less clear. When a programmer sees `document.getElementById` they will know what that means. When a programmer sees `byId` they will have no idea what action is being done (there's no verb) or what sort of Id might  possibly be being referred to. They will then look up the definition and see `document.getElementById`, which defeats any purported readability gain from wrapping it.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage does not have significant performance drawbacks. It's also not error prone, unless you're referencing other scripts that can potentially also define a `byId()` method in the global scope. The only advantage I see, other than easy of use for yourself, is reducing the `JavaScript` size the client browser needs to download if there is heavy usage of `document.getElementById()`.