# Calling function stored in variable results in different behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to dynamically call a function, which is stored in a variable, targetListener:

```
>chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener==targetListener
true
```

So, chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener refers to the same function as targetListener.

I then have a callback:

```
>callback=function(info){console.log("hello")}
undefined
```

And I try to add this callback, first in the "normal" way:

```
>chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(callback)
undefined
```

But when I try to do so via the "targetListener" variable, I get:

```
targetListener(callback)
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A variable can reference the same function with a different context. Maybe that comes into play here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773579/if-javascript-has-first-class-functions-why-doesnt-this-work

Comment: I think that answers the question

Comment: Unfortunately, that question doesn't seem searchable enough from someone who runs into this issue

Comment: @erjoalgo That's why we have duplicates. Others may find your question, and then they'll be redirected to a canonical answer :)