# javascript, assigning requestAnimationFrame & cancelAnimationFrame to properties of an object

Tags: javascript, this, requestanimationframe, native-methods

```
//
// version 1
//
var requestAnimFram = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequsetAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        }
})();

//version 1 usage
function main(){
    //main loop
    ...
    requestAnimFram(main);
}
main();

//
// version 2
//
var animFram = {
    req: window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        },
    ccl: window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozCancelAnimationFrame,
    myReq: 0
};

//version 2 usage
function main(){
    ...
    aniFram.myReq = aniFram.req(main);
}
main();

function stop(){
    aniFram.ccl(myReq);
}
```

While I was exploring some example codes, I found `requestAnimationFrame`. version 1 is carved from that and it works fine. After seaching for a while, I found `cancelAnimationFrame` as well and wanted to use both of them. So I made a dummy page for test. The version 2 is carved from it.

The problem is that, it doesn't loop. So, I have two questions.

1. Is it impossible to use `requestAnimationFrame` in this way? If so, why exactly so?
2. If it's possible-but I'm doing it in wrong way, how can I acheive this?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your module : `ccl: ccl,
        myReq: 0; // Remove semicolon`

Comment: "*It works fine unless I try to twist it.*" - then show us how you tried to twist it, please.

Comment: 1) It's fine to edit a question to make it better, but make sure not to change it into a completely different question especially if there already are answers. 2) You can delete your own comments by clicking on the (X), you could flag mine as "obsolete" but it's easier when I remove them myself.

Comment: @Nathan P. Would you delete your comment, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi All is done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is a duplicate(["Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome)). But I'm still gonna answer my own question with more detail, as such could help others to understand this matter in a different way.

> 1. Is it impossible to use requestAnimationFrame in this way? If so, why exactly so?

It is impossible.

> 2. If it's possible-but I'm doing it in wrong way, how can I acheive this?

This problem, by itself, can be easily fixed by using `call()` and `bind()` and `apply()` methods.

```
//Using call()
//Attach call method during invocation
aniFram.req.call(window, main);

//Using bind()
//Attach bind method during the object initialization
aniFram = {
    req: requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    ...
}
aniFram.req(main);

//Using apply()
//Attach apply method during invocation
aniFram.req.apply(window, [main]);
```

Notice the similarity in here that all 3 methods somehow have an additional parameter 'window'. They all have a same reason for it: `requestAnimationFrame` is a method of `window` object that requires the context of `window`.

`aniFram` is an object. It has a method `req` which references the `window.requestAnimationFrame`. `aniFram.req(main)` invokes the `window.requestAnimationFrame` in the context of the `aniFram`, not `window`. That's why it doesn't work. Let's consider another example code:

#### Example Code

```
var obj1 = {
    target: 'Jake',
    hitman: function(){
        this.target = 'RIP';
    }
};
var obj2 = {
    //assigns obj1.hitman to obj2.hitman
    hitman: obj1.hitman
};  
obj2.hitman();
console.log(obj1.target); //outputs 'Jake'

/////////////////////////////////////////
//call() method
obj2.hitman.call(obj1);
console.log(obj1.target); //outputs 'RIP'

//apply() method
obj2.hitman.apply(obj1);
console.log(obj1.target); //outputs 'RIP'

//bind() method
var obj2 = {
    hitman: obj1.hitman.bind(obj1)
};
obj2.hitman();
console.log(obj1.target); //outputs 'RIP'
```

This is exactly same situation as your code, version 2. You invoke `obj2.hitman()` that references `obj1.hitman` expecting to change the value of `obj1.target`, but it does nothing. Because what `obj1.hitman` does is executing a statement `this.target = 'RIP'`. Since it is executed in the context of `obj2`, this statement becomes `obj2.target = 'RIP'`. There is no `target` property in obj2.

#### call, apply, bind

That's where these methods kick in. Without them, Javascript Engine determines context automatically (current object. ie. aniFram, obj2). By attaching these methods to your code, now you can decide in which context it will be executed (ie. window, obj1).

---

This is also called as an Alias Function. ([If Javascript has first-class functions, why doesn't this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773579/if-javascript-has-first-class-functions-why-doesnt-this-work))