# how can I alias document.getElementById.onclick to d.id.c in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to alias javascript function : 
[I have readfrom this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773579/if-javascript-has-first-class-functions-why-doesn-t-calling-this-function-in-a)

I want to alias **document.getElementById.onclick** as **d.id.c**

I tried :

```
var d = document;
d['i'] = d.getElementById.bind(d);
d.i['c'] = d.i.onclick.bind(d.i);
```

HTML :

```
<div id="myid">Button</div>
```

Javascript :

```
d.i("myid").onclick = function(){
   alert("clicked"); // Working well
} 

// but

d.i("myid").c = function(){
   alert("clicked"); // not working
}
```

Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mutate the built-in `document` object - rather, you can create a standalone variable `d` which has an `i` method, which, when passed an `id`, calls `document.getElementById(id)` and returns an object with a `c` setter. When the setter is called, assign the element's `onclick` property to the passed handler:

```js
const d = {
  i(id) {
    const elm = document.getElementById(id);
    return {
      set c(handler) {
        elm.onclick = handler;
      }
    }
  }
};

d.i("myid").c = function() {
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

```html
<div id="myid">Button</div>
```

If you also want to be able to access standard properties of the element *in addition to* using `.c = <handler>`, then use `Object.create` on the element, and return that new object:

```js
const d = {
  i(id) {
    const elm = document.getElementById(id);
    const obj = Object.create(elm);
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'c', {
      set(handler) {
        elm.onclick = handler;
      }
    });
    return obj;
  }
};

d.i("myid").c = function() {
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

```html
<div id="myid">Button</div>
```

(technically, you could also just define the property on `elm` itself, but that can cause problems in unusual situations, like if other scripts are depending on a custom `c` property, thus `Object.create`)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var d = document;

d['i'] = id => ({ 
  set c(f) { document.getElementById(id).onclick=f } 
});


d.i("myid").c = function() {
   alert("clicked"); 
}
```

```html
<div id="myid">Button</div>
```

however is not recomended to change document object - so better change `var d=document` to just `var d={}`